# IE, Safari: Localisation using l10n.js on client-side

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, localization, safari

I am using L10n.js (https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/) for passively localizing a cpl of strings in  one of the features in my application.

For some reason on IE and Safari, the demo (http://code.eligrey.com/l10n.js/demo.html) always shows up in American English (my current locale). This happens even if I have nothing but French in my browser settings. It works well for FF and Chrome but for IE and Safari, it defaults to the user's current locale regardless of the browser's language setting. Any idea about why this is happening and how I could resolve this.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.locale` to manually configure the locale for testing.